# If a power adds a damage roll to a static damage power, is bonus damage applied?

Tags: dnd-4e

In dnd 4e, if I have a +4 weapon and use concussive response and brutal barrage (+7 con), how much damage is applied?

Comment: Hi Kayla, welcome to the site!  Good first questions, please take a look around and take a look at the [FAQ].

Answer (score 6):

**Extra damage is not a "damage roll"**

As per [here](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/26530885/Any_ways_to_cheese_out_magic_missile&post_num=3#479596673):

> First of all, extra damage is not a damage roll, even though you roll damage. Counter-intuitive I know, but the term "damage roll" refers exclusively to the damage listed in the power, so there is no way to "add" a damage roll to a power.

Therefore, it would do 7+1d6 damage, despite character builder potentially erroring out and giving you bonus damage as per [here](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/28273717/Galstaff%3a_Making_Magic_Missile_the_best_power_ever).